# RequireJS not loading Firebase, undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, firebase

I'm trying to make a simple Firebase application using RequireJS and it is failing to pull in Firebase for some reason. I created a basic example that shows my problem.

Project structure is this:

```
/index.html
/js/main.js
/js/vendor/firebase.js
/js/vendor/require.js
/js/vendor/jquery.min.js
```

**index.html** includes:

```
<script src='js/vendor/require.js' data-main="js/main"></script>
```

**main.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': "vendor/jquery.min",
        'firebase': "vendor/firebase"
    }
});

require(["firebase", "jquery"], function (firebase, $) {
    "use strict";

    console.log(firebase);  // undefined
    console.log($);         // function m(a, b)
});
```

Why does jquery load fine but firebase does not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out. Firebase does not support AMD by default, so need to add it as a shim in the require.js config:

**main.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': "vendor/jquery.min",
        'firebase': "vendor/firebase"
    },
    shim: {
        'firebase': {
            exports: 'firebase'
        }
    }
});
```